# Live CD boot: SQUASHFS error: unable to read xattr id index table

Tags: boot, mount, initramfs

I am creating custm squashfs of Ubuntu.

Currently, I am facing this error:

```
[ ... ] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read xattr id index table
```

It can be reproduced by executing in initramfs

```
mount /cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs /filesystem.squashfs -t squashfs -o loop
```

- [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336840/27328)

Without the `-o loop` it is the same.

but when I run the command in the running Ubuntu, all is fine:

```
sudo mount /media/USER/UUI/casper/filesystem.squashfs fs-uui -t squashfs -o loop
```

Notes:

- The image which produces the error can be found [here](https://owncloud.quelltext.eu/index.php/s/KrnIDAAWea97FrD).
- To see the error message at boot, I removed the `splash` and `quiet` options in the boot command.
- md5sums are all right.

If you have suggestions on how to debug this or how you create your custom iso image booting with efi, please leave a note.

---

EDIT 1:
Currently, the workaround is to remove the xattrs from the root filesystem with the `-no-xattrs` option:

```
mksquashfs / "$filesystem_location/filesystem.squashfs" -ef ./exclude.txt -wildcards -no-xattrs
```

---

Edit 2: The error still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You write, you can mount the squashfs from a fully booted system, but you cannot mount it when booting. This suggests, that you are missing a Kernel module in your initramdrive.

During boot, only modules from the initrd images are available.

In the running system you can issue `lsmod` to view a list of loaded modules. When mounting the squash image the kernel should be forced to load some additional driver modules. Issuing `lsmod` before and after the mount, you should be able to see what modules were loaded during the mount.

Enter those modules into `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and rebuild your initrd using `update-initramfs -u`.